# Create df column concatenated value over each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a new column in my DataFrame which is a json string equivalent to concatenated column values over each row in the below format?

Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nat', 'Harry', 'Jack'],'Age':[20, 21, 22, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input df:

```
  Name  Age
0    Tom   20
1   Nat   21
2  Harry   22
3   Jack   23
```

Output df:

```
  Name  Age Combined
0    Tom   20   [{"Name":"Tom","Age":20}]
1   Nat   21    [{"Name":"Nat","Age":21}]
2  Harry   22   [{"Name":"Harry","Age":22}]
3   Jack   23   [{"Name":"Jack","Age":23}]
```

Comment: Basically I want the output of `df.to_json(orient='records')` for each row

Comment: Done. I tried to use `df = df.join(pd.Series(df.to_json(orient='records'),index=df.index,name='combined'))` but that concatenates the entire df for each row. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nat', 'Harry', 'Jack'],'Age':[20, 21, 22, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Combined'] = '[{"'+str(df.columns[0])+'": "'+df['Name']+'", "'+str(df.columns[1])+'": '+df['Age'].apply(str)+'}]'
```

it works but there may be better ways to do this

```
    Name    Age Combined
0   Tom     20  [{"Name": "Tom", "Age": 20}]
1   Nat     21  [{"Name": "Nat", "Age": 21}]
2   Harry   22  [{"Name": "Harry", "Age": 22}]
3   Jack    23  [{"Name": "Jack", "Age": 23}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your output as a serialized `string`: This solution works independent of the columns but is not vectorized and slow. [@PaulBrennan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64900978/14277722) should be faster for larger dataframes if you can construct the string manually.

```
df['Combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: f'[{x.to_json()}]', axis=1)
df
```

Out:

```
    Name  Age                     Combined
0    Tom   20    [{"Name":"Tom","Age":20}]
1    Nat   21    [{"Name":"Nat","Age":21}]
2  Harry   22  [{"Name":"Harry","Age":22}]
3   Jack   23   [{"Name":"Jack","Age":23}]
```